# pandas drop duplicates based upon duplicate columns and one similar column

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Given this sample set of data:

```
ID    Name     Address
2     Smith    123 Main Street, Redwood, IL, 12345
2     Smith    123 Main, Redwood, 12345
2     Smith    123 Mn Street, Redwood, 12345
2     Smith    456 E. Wallace Drive, Morona, Washington
```

How would I use pandas to drop duplicates which would handle the first three rows leaving the fourth row intact?  Obviously, I can drop duplicates based upon the first two columns, but that would be an error since it would leave only one of the 4 above row intact.  The goal is to somehow drop duplicates if the first two rows are identical and the third row has n number of characters in common.  I have tried various drop duplicates versions and, of course, nothing quite gets it there.  How to drop duplicates based upon two columns as duplicates and a third column based upon n number of characters in common between two strings?

The expected output would be:

```
ID    Name     Address
2     Smith    123 Mn Street, Redwood, 12345
2     Smith    456 E. Wallace Drive, Morona, Washington
```

Comment: There are no exact duplicates among these addresses. What you would like instead is to flag **near-duplicates**. That is a domain-dependent and relatively complex topic. What logic would you use to flag such near duplicates? (I can think of a number of plausible ones, including one that involves a full address parser and that is clearly out of scope for a SO question).

Answer (score 0):

As @PierreD told you, the task is not simple if you want to do it properly. Nevertheless, here is a quick pointer on how to extract the first number of the address and use it to add a novel level to detect duplicates:

```
df['Number'] = df['Address'].str.extract('(\d+)')
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID', 'Name', 'Number'])
```

output:

```
   ID   Name                                   Address Number
0   2  Smith       123 Main Street, Redwood, IL, 12345    123
3   2  Smith  456 E. Wallace Drive, Morona, Washington    456
```